# Flask-PyMongo and init_app()

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I'm doing a clean-up of my development environment. I have code that was running fine, but I wanted to remove any conflict between the various mongo drivers. However now I'm perplexed by the error generated from the following set-up

```
<app.py>

from database import mongo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
mongo.init_app(app)
```

and `<database.py>`

```
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
mongo = PyMongo()
```

gives the following error:

```
  mongo.init_app(app)
  File "/home/x/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_pymongo/__init__.py", line 232, in init_app
    cx = connection_cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 342, in __init__
    for k, v in keyword_opts.items())
  File "/home/x/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 342, in <genexpr>
    for k, v in keyword_opts.items())
  File "/home/x/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 465, in validate
    value = validator(option, value)
  File "/home/x/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 107, in raise_config_error
    raise ConfigurationError("Unknown option %s" % (key,))
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: Unknown option auto_start_request
```

in my requirements.txt I have: `Flask-PyMongo==0.3.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using `PyMongo<3.0` version.

`auto_start_request` client method [was removed](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/22fd629968527edcacf08322df60a4bf92572f65/doc/changelog.rst#changes-in-version-30) in 3.0 release and changes added to `Flask-PyMongo==0.4.1`.

So you should either upgrade `Flask-PyMongo` or downgrade `PyMongo` package.